# Elasticsearch prefixFilter for a facet

Tags: java, elasticsearch, faceted-search

Very new to elasticsearch, using the Java client.

Is it possible to return facet counts filtered on a prefix?

For example, I'm searching for URLs and want to ignore the path, and just count the hostname. Eg,

```
addFacet( filterFacet("myhost", prefixFilter("url", "http://myhost.com"))
```

In the response the facets are all empty. No names or values.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to store the part that you want to facet on as a separate field. Alternatively, you can use [Term Scripts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) to extract the prefix on the fly.